# Using @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackageClasses = "myApp") in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, kotlin

I've added the following annotation:

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "myApp")
```

Works fine in Java, but the Kotlin compiler gives:

```
(40, 51): Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but kotlin.Array<kotlin.reflect.KClass<*>> was expected
```

Comment: It is better to include the code directly into the question instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an array is expected, Java will auto-box a single value into a singleton array. In Kotlin, you can use:

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("myApp"))
```

Comment: Ah, if it was a simple typo like that would be nice. Adding a screenshot.

Comment: @chyrlis Sounds like a common typo, but in my case it wasn't that. It looks like something related to mapping kotlin types to java?

Comment: @JasperBlues Once you changed it to `basePackages`, did the error message change? Note that the values for both parameters are array-valued, and Java will autobox a single value into a singleton array.